# Whether react-native support changing device orientation at runtime in Android?

Tags: android, react-native

I am using `react-native` to create an Android app and I am looking for a way to change android device orientation at runtime. After searching through google, most of the answers relate to third party library such as `react-native-navigation`, `react-native-navigation-controller` etc. I have tried some of them but none of them working. I wander whether `react-native` supports this feature officially.